# Visual Studio Professional Remote Debug Arm64 program on Ubuntu with Qemu

Tags: visual-studio, gdb, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging, gdbserver

Is it possible to perform remote debugging using Visual Studio Professional running on Windows, cross compiled arm64 program running on Linux x86 Ubuntu using qemu-aarch64 ?

It works well to compile x86 program and debug directly on Linux using Visual Studio. I was able also to compile arm64  program, but I'm not able to attach debugger from visual studio.

Currently sample code I try to compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int i = 10;
    printf("Helo, I'm executinr ARM64 %d.\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it using command:

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-pie -ggdb3 -no-pie -o hello hello.c
```

In Visual studio I had to change compiler to: aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc and compilation works well.

For debugging I use commands (natively from Ubuntu):

```
qemu-aarch64 -L /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu -g 1238 ./hello

gdb-multiarch -q --nh -ex 'set architecture arm64' -ex 'file hello' -ex 'target remote localhost:1238' -ex 'layout split' -ex 'layout regs'
```

Is it possible to somehow adjust the systems to perform debugging from Visual Studio Professional ?

I have tried many different options but none of them worked.